# Crystal Reports Delphi 7 VCL - setting CurrentValue for Date Range Parameter

Tags: delphi, parameters, crystal-reports, report, vcl

im using the Crystal Reports VCL for Delphi 7 to run Crystal Reports from Delphi. I want to set current parameter values from this Delphi application. I'm sending succesfully this values for Number or String Parameters. But now i'm struggling with Date Parameters that have  set `Allow Ranges` to `True`.

The Error im getting is: `305:Error converting string to ValueInfo - ParamFields[2].CurrentValues.Add <StrToValueInfo>`

I'm using this code which like i said works for *no Range* Parameters. In the code below the parameter `PARAM_DATE` is a Date parameter which allows Ranges. Any idea how to pass range values?

```
procedure TReportFrame.btnExecuteReportClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    Crpe1 : TCrpe;
    varArr : variant;
    i : integer;
    a : TCrpeParamFieldRangesItem;
    b : TCrpeParamFieldCurrentValuesItem;
begin
  SetCurrentDir( GetCommonFilesPath );
  try
  Crpe1 := TCrpe.Create(Self);
  Crpe1.DiscardSavedData();
  Crpe1.ReportName := getReportBasePath() + reportFileName;

  Crpe1.IgnoreKnownProblems := true;
  Crpe1.LoadEngineOnUse := true;
  Crpe1.Connect.Clear;

  Crpe1.Tables[0].ConnectBuffer := glbDBMan.GetConnectionString;

    Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_SORTING_TYPE', EmptyStr).CurrentValue :=  VarToStr( paramSposobSortowania.getSelectedValue());

  varArr := parameterOsobaOdpowiedzialna.getSelectedValues();
  for i := VarArrayLowBound(varArr,1) to VarArrayHighBound(varArr,1) do
  begin
    Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_PERSON', EmptyStr).CurrentValues.Add(VarToStr( varArr[i]));
  end;

//  Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATA_ZLOZENIA_WNIOSKU', EmptyStr).CurrentValues.Add('2012-4-1');
//  a := TCrpeParamFieldRangesItem.Create;
//  a.RangeStart := '2012-4-1';
//  a.RangeEnd := '2012-4-6';
//  Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).Ranges.Add();
//  Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).Ranges[0].RangeStart := '2012-4-1';
//  Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).Ranges[0].RangeEnd := '2012-4-6';

//  Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).CurrentValues.Add('2012-4-1');

    //PARAM_DATE is a DATE Range
  Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).CurrentValues.Add('2012-4-1');
  Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).CurrentValues.Add('2012-4-6');

  if Crpe1.Connect.Test then
    Crpe1.Show
  else
    ShowMessage('Error Connecting');

    Crpe1.DiscardSavedData;

    finally
      SetCurrentDir( ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0)) );
    end;
end;
```

Comment: OK i found out that if i put the date is this format 2012,4,7 (commas instead of minuses) it works. BUt this way i can only pass one value. i still cannot pass a range...

Comment: Use FastReport instead of Crystal Report  in delphi projects.FastReport is easier and faster than CR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).Ranges.Add();
Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).Ranges[0].RangeStart := '2012,4,1';
Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).Ranges[0].RangeEnd := '2012,4,6';
```

UPDATE: there is a function in the VCL (file: UCrpeUtl) called *CrDateToStr* which takes a TDateTime and returns this format of a date string.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
i:= Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).Ranges.Add();
Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).Ranges.Items[i].RangeStart := '2012-4-1';
Crpe1.ParamByName('PARAM_DATE', EmptyStr).Ranges.Itens[i].RangeEnd := '2012-4-6';
```

Comment: yep, tried it. In the end it started working after i replace minuses with commas.